# Match LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME and replace with FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME with regular expressions

Tags: regex

I haven't had to use regular expressions in some time, I find myself trying

```
(?<lastName>[A-Za-z]+\,) (?<firstName>[A-Za-z]+)
```

as a matching pattern, but I think I'm going down the wrong path, let alone the replacement pattern, which is why I thought I would return pattern names.

Comment: Which language or regex engine are you using?

Comment: Is your input a name by itself, or a name within other text?

Comment: PCRE for the regex engine. The input is just a last_name, first_name

Comment: Be aware that not everyone in the world has a simple “firstname lastname” name … so any code/regex relying on this to be the case will work in a very restricted environment only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
([a-zA-Z]+), ([a-zA-Z]+)
```

with:

```
$2 $1
```

Comment: Yes, perfect, thanks. Now to tweak it to accommodate those who have included one or more middle initials! Anyway, this works great.